# Como escolher apenas alguns itens de um .map

Tags: javascript, html, css, react, redux

Estou fazendo um aplicativo parecido com o facebook, todas as postagens estão em um .map:

```
{datapost !== undefined && datapost.map(item => {
                        return (
                            <div className="publicacao">
                                <div className="conteudo">

                                    <div className="title">
                                        <div className="title-content">
                                            <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="title-btn">

                                            <button
                                                onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}>
                                                <img src={trash} alt="botão excluir" />
                                            </button>
                                            <ModalDelete
                                                show={modalShow}
                                                onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="username">
                                        <p>@{item.username}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="content">
                                        <h3>{item.content}</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr />
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
```

Já usei o redux para salvar o id da publicação que o usuário cria, preciso listar as opções de editar e deletar apenas para esses id's. mas não sei como.

aqui esta o botão de deletar post:

```
<button
   onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}>
   <img src={trash} alt="botão excluir" />
</button>
<ModalDelete
   show={modalShow}
   onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
 />
```

aqui o modal que o botão abre:

```
return (
        <Modal
            {...props}
            size="lg"
            aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
            centered
            style={{ fontFamily: "Questrial" }}
        >
            <Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                    DELETE THE POST
                </Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <p>
                    are you sure?
                </p>
                <Button onClick={Delete}>YES</Button>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button onClick={props.onHide}>CLOSE</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    );
```

aqui ta o redux que salva o id:

```
const [idvalue, setIdvalue] = useState([])
    
    const ids = useSelector(
        state => state.data,
        [idvalue]);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // action
    function addID(params) {
        dispatch({ type: 'ADD_ID', id: idvalue })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perdão se entendi errado, você quer somente que alguns elementos do .map seja retornado?
Se for isso, você pode passar um filter antes do .map, por exemplo:

```
datapost.filter((elemento) => elemento.title !== 'Titulo').map((item) =>...
```

Nesse caso do exemplo, o array retornado será tudo menos o elemento.title que seu valor seja 'Título'.

Você pode utilizar mais parametros, recomendo dar uma olhada [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) na documentação.